# What is the meaning of "solid" in terms of quality and performance?

Tags: word-usage

Solid as in "solid performer", "solid performance" or "solid act". Does it mean good or average or something in between?

Comment: It's trivial extension from the more literal *built on a **solid foundation*** - the literal foundation or metaphoric performance has ***no weak parts***.

Comment: [Try consulting a solid dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/solid): "of good substantial quality or kind; sound; made firmly and well; reliable". The last of these actually has the example "a solid performer":  you can rely on them to give a good performance.

Answer (score 0):

It means "good". It means "lacking in any significant flaws".  Not exceptional, and perhaps without flair or genius.

> Mary put in a solid performance in midfield. She passed accurately and had a role in the second goal.